# How to record a two-way conversation in UWP using speakers and microphone

Tags: c#, uwp, loopback, wasapi, speaker

I want to record a two-way conversation using a speaker and microphone in my UWP app. Currently I am able to record using a microphone, and generate an audio file using a microphone, but now I want to allow the user to select both microphone and speaker and generate two files for speaker and microphone, e.g when the user uses Skype call my UWP app should be able to record both my voice (Microphone) and the recipient's voice (Speaker).

Is it possible using WASAPI and stereo mix? How do we implement it in UWP code (C#)?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible using WASAPI and stereo mix? How do we implement it in UWP code(C#).

You could not make a recorder plugin to record audio stream comes from other apps with uwp. And WASAPI does not provide such api to approach. If you want to capture the audio comes from your live chat app, the recorder should be internal, not plugin. The simple principle can be to write audio streams from the microphone and headphones on the same timeline.